# Generic Type Argument on Class/Interface level vs only on method level

Tags: java, generics

Consider these two interface declarations:

```
interface TransformShapeA {
    <T extends Shape> T applyTransformation(T shape);
}
```

and:

```
interface TransformShapeB<T extends Shape> {
    T applyTransformation(T shape);
}
```

Can you please elaborate what do we gain by using `TransformShapeA` that we do not when using `TransformShapeB`?

In which scenario we would like to actually make a constraint to **not allow** implementations for specific Shape?

Comment: You can implement additional methods `TransformShapeA` of different generics and you don't need to define the class at implementation

Comment: `TransformShapeA` is not actually something you can realistically implement.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm fully aware of that. Since it's a valid construction, I was wondering if I'm missing some real usage scenario where this is actually helpful and needed.

Comment: No, you aren't.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, that is a valid point of what it can do. I'm more interested if there is a need to have an implementation in the form which `TransformShapeA` provides over the `TransformShapeB`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Why don't you provide a constructive comment if you disagree?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for.  You seem to have correctly reached the conclusion that you cannot actually implement this interface.  I'm not sure what "use cases" you expect to find for something that's not actually possible.  There are many, many ways of writing code that has no point or cannot work, and you seem to know you have found one.

Comment: `public class WidthDoubler implements TransformShapeA {

    @Override
    public <T extends Shape> T applyTransformation(T shape) {
        shape.setWidth(shape.getWidth() * 2);
        return shape;
    }
}`

I do agree that this construction may not be useful as you can achieve the same by using `WidthDobulerB<T extends Shape> implements TransformShapeB<T>`. I was just wondering if there is a use case where the `TransformShapeA` may be what we want and that I was missing it.